# GetCharacterIndexFromPoint in Silverlight

Tags: c#, .net, silverlight

Is there any equivalent for GetCharacterIndexFromPoint in Silverlight?
Or any other method to determine, where my object is droped (from drag and drop method)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your best bet is to use [RichTextBox.GetPositionFromPoint](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff382848%28v=vs.95%29.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Since Silverlight supports [GetRectFromCharacterIndex()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms603095%28v=VS.95%29.aspx), you can use it to reimplement `GetCharacterIndexFromPoint()` (but it will problably be slower, and unfortunately won't support the `snapToText` argument).

Something like (untested):

```
public static int GetCharacterIndexFromPoint(this TextBox textBox, Point point)
{
    try {
        return Enumerable.Range(0, textBox.Text.Length).First(
            index => {
                Rectangle rect = textBox.GetRectFromCharacterIndex(index, false);
                rect.Union(textBox.GetRectFromCharacterIndex(index, true));
                return rect.Contains(point);
            });
    } catch (InvalidOperationException) {
        // No character lies at specified point.
        return -1;
    }
}
```

Comment: When I'm trying to use GetRectFromCharacterIndex method on textbox there is "The method or operation is not implemented." exception. 
Maybe you know, what should I do?

Comment: It looks like you're using Silverlight 3 or lower. This method is only supported from Silverlight 4 onwards. Maybe you can upgrade?

Comment: It looks like the GetRectFromCharacterIndex is not avilable in silverlight other than this for Windows Phone 7

Comment: Ah, so you're running Windows Phone 6? Indeed it looks like this method is not supported there...

Comment: No, I'm running on standart Silverlight 4 for web browsers. I just tested it on clean project in SL4 and project for Windows Phone 7 (MSDN doc tell, that it is supported by WP7) and in SL4 it is not working, but WP7 is corect. Question is - is there any opportunity for realize task (drop in correct place) in silverlight 4 for web browsers.

Comment: Strange then, the documentation says this method is supported by Silverlight 4 and 5. Are you sure you're extending the WPF `TextBox` class (`System.Windows.Controls.TextBox`) and not the Windows Forms one (`System.Windows.Forms.TextBox`)?